# microphone access for voice recognition inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, voice-recognition, voice-recording

I have code which runs inside chrome and uses the [chrome's voice recognition javascript API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API?hl=en). I have followed the code as in the link and it works when inside a normal toplevel  of the html. Microphone access prompt pops up when ever I try to access microphone. However I would like the iframe the page inside another page due to some legacy application logics. Inside an iframe the code executes but the prompt for microphone access doesnt pop up when the code executes.

```
            this.showInfo("Initalizing");
            /* jshint ignore:start */
            var WebkitSpeechRecognition = webkitSpeechRecognition;
            recognition = new WebkitSpeechRecognition();
            /* jshint ignore:end */
            recognition.continuous = true;
            recognition.interimResults = true;

            recognition.onstart = this.__onstart;
            recognition.onerror = this.__onerror;
            recognition.onend = this.__onend;
            recognition.onresult = this.__onresult;
            recognition.showInfo = this.showInfo;
```

Comment: The two documents are on the same domain? If not, you're probably facing some CORS issue, otherwise, I think it should work, at least it does on my localhost

Comment: yes same domain they are